# To get the value in header section

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I started to develop a plugin and i write the code bellow

```
add_filter('get_header', 'my_postslide');
```

It is calling the function in body part, but now i want to get the value in the header part.
It means in the `<header> </header>` part.Please let me know what the appropriate hook for call the value in the  "`<header> </header>`" part.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `wp_head`hook. see here in WordPress codex : http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_head

Comment: i want to use in the page "<header> </header>" section.

Comment: Did you read the link I sent? : It precisely says "The wp_head action hook is triggered within the <head></head> section of the user's template by the wp_head() function." Usually, `wp_head();`is placed in the user's themes just before the closing `</head>`tag. So if you use this hook, you can, indeed, place elements **inside** `<head>...</head>` section.